# Best way to properly name files within zip archive

Tags: php, file-upload, zip

I have a function that creates zip files when passed an array of files which works beautifully.

```
$zip_file = create_zip($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'],$target);
```

But what happens is that the files in the zip archive all have the tmp names and no extensions. What would be the best way to alter the array I pass to the function such that the files are named the same way as when they are uploaded?

Comment: is [this](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php) your `create_zip`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. It takes an array of files and returns an archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've rewritten `create_zip` to include a `localnames` parameter. Pass in the `$_FILES['myfile']['name']` for the files' original names.

```
function create_zip($files = array(),$localnames=array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
  //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
  if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
  //vars
  $valid_files = array();
  //if files were passed in...
  if(is_array($files)) {
    //cycle through each file
    foreach($files as $file) {
      //make sure the file exists
      if(file_exists($file)) {
        $valid_files[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }
  //if we have good files...
  if(count($valid_files)) {
    //create the archive
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
      return false;
    }
    //add the files to archive
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($valid_files); $i++) {
      $zip->addFile($valid_files[$i],$localnames[$i]);
    }
    //debug
    //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

    //close the zip -- done!
    $zip->close();

    //check to make sure the file exists
    return file_exists($destination);
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
$zip_file = create_zip($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['myfile']['name'],
    $target);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was just what I was looking for.

Note: To any one else who comes across to use this - in the above code [i] should be replaced with [$i] for it to work properly.

Comment: @aman88, awesome, glad to help! (Thanks for fixing that error—wasn't paying enough attention.)